# Are these termite droppings (aka frass)?

Tags: pest-control, pest, termite

Are these termite droppings. If so, can I do some sort of localized treatment?

This house was tented in the past 4 years. This is the only place I’ve seen any kind of pest.

[image]

Updating this question with some new images, since there was some confusion about the context. Here is an establishing shot:
[image]

Here is a close up of the suspected frass:
[image]

Here is a close up of the top of the window, where I speculate the frass is being pushed out of the wood and falling onto the sill below:
[image]

Comment: Have you ruled out the plant right next to your problem as a possible source?

Comment: @Olivier the droppings were there before the plant was.

Comment: I believe that if you had termites, what you would expect to see would be a small pile of sawdust.  Small mammal does seem more likely.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had two pest inspections done and both agreed this is frass from dry wood termites.

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to say for sure as the photo gives to size reference but I think these are mouse "pills" or dropping and not termites.

Set a couple of mouse traps after cleaning this up and you will know.

Comment: Mice . I have had termites three times and never saw "droppings".

Comment: This is a windowsill. These are pretty small. Too small for mice, I’d think.

Comment: Look like tiny seeds. Has the window been open?

Comment: Looks like insect frass, but termites dont run around in the open.

Comment: Changing my vote to cockroaches; too small for mice.

Answer (score -1):

By the amount of hair on the sill, I'd include flea dirt on the list of possibilities. Do you have an itchy cat? Flea dirt will run red like blood when wet (since that is what they feed on).

Comment: You might want to take note that the OP answered her own question 10 months ago based on a professional pest inspection and it was, in fact, termite droppings, not fleas.